# Expressing exponential functions

Tags: laplace-transform

Can someone provide me a list of the important complex exponential functions. For example, $\cos (at) = \large \frac{e^{iat} +e^{-iat}}{2}$. I am trying to find the laplace transformation for a given function by definition and it helps to know how to convert a $cosat$ or $sinat$ to a exponential function. I googled it, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "complex exponential functions"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan like for an example , expressing cosat in terms of complex exponential functions $\cos (at) = \large \frac{e^{iat} +e^{-iat}}{2}$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The question tells me to take the laplace transform by definition for cosat and they expressed the cosat in terms of those exponential function to simplify the integration calculation.

Comment: What is 'cosat'? Doesn't it want to be $\cos(at)$ where, I guess, $a$ is constant and $t$ is the variable?

Comment: @Berci yes , sorry for not clarifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Relationship_to_exponential_function_and_complex_numbers

You can find all the trig functions here, and their relationship to complex exponentials.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I was looking for.